# Java: Load class while jar-file is updated

Tags: java, jar, noclassdeffounderror

My Java program loads classes dynamically at runtime. All classes are located in the same jar.

After deploying a new jar file, I sometimes get errors while the jar file is copying (NoClassDefFoundError etc.). This goes away the next time I run the program of course. Is there a way to preload classes so that my program is not affected when updating the jar?

I guess I could create instances of all classes and then clone() them, but perhaps there's a better way?

Comment: Explain how is your app is loading dinamically the classes, simply "Class.forName"? Or something more complex to dinamically reload renewed jars? If it's the case you could make a dir rename to get the new classpath changed without waiting for a file copy. Or maybe using your own class-loaders (it's not difficult, I can guide you)

Comment: I think I may try a custom class-loader. I have read some articles and it should be interesting to spend some time on this.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you load all the classes, you may still get errors from resources.

I suggest deploying to a different location if at all possible. Alternatively, if you can manager the class loading, copy the jar to a temporary file (which is automatically done for http URLs, for instance) or into memory.